# Does the Samsung Galaxy A30 support HDMI and/or MHL?

Tags: samsung, hdmi, mhl, usb-c

Dad's phone is a Samsung Galaxy A30. We've got several TVs and monitors but none are smart TVs or capable of screencasting. But some have HDMI.

I have a USB C to HDMI adaptor that works with my M1 MacBook Air that I expected would work with the A30 too but it did not.

Most info about Samsung's HDMI / MHL support I can find is about how Samsung's older micro USB version was nonstandard, having a different number of pins. But there's a lot less info about the newer ones that have USB C.

I can find sites trying to sell aftermarket cables and adaptors for this phone but I don't trust them. So far none of the pages on the A30's specs I can find specifically state that HDMI or MHL is either supported or not supported, it's just not in the list.

Comment: **No**, as you can see from the site dedicated to [listing MHL devices](https://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1)

Comment: Besides, OEMs won't neglect mentioning any point that can drive sales, so if it's not mentioned by them, it's safe to assume it doesn't

Comment: On devices with USB-C a DisplayPort Alt Mode is more likely than an HDMI Alt Mode. The latter was defined years after the Displayport version and is not much used. On Samsung devices search for the "Dex" mode to see which devices support an external display. For (wrireless) screen casting to dumb TVs you can use a Google Chromecast dongle.